# Improve the build speed of Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Does any one face long time build process to run a website with visual studio 2019 and asp.net?
I tried to Free up some space in the disk and End up some tasks to free RAM memory, clear visual studio cashe but the peoblem still

Any suggestion regarding this issue, it is so frustrating to develop with such speed.

SOLVED
This was solved by setting source control to None and disable stratup in the task manager and followed the instructions posted below

Comment: Check this maybe you can get some ideas from [**10 Tips to Improve Visual Studio Build Performance**](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1042975/Tips-to-Improve-Visual-Studio-Build-Performance) by Kailash Shastri

Comment: What do you consider a "long time"? How complex is your solution? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Are you talking build time, or the time AFTER the build to launch the web site. I find that build time is fast - but once the build is completed, then I find the time for the browser to launch, and the web page to display - that's taking VERY long for one of my applications - about 8 seconds. But the build time is still very sort. So I never seen build time take a long time. This should in effect be good news - since long build times are not a common - and thus can usually be fixed.

Comment: No launching the website after build taking so much time, I have 16 RAM, 10th Gen Intel core.

Comment: Here are more tips and tooling like Visual Studio Build Timer extension, Solution Filters, Incremental Analysis investigation, to improve Visual Studio Build Performance https://blog.ndepend.com/improve-visual-studio-build-performance/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@ Nadin Martini.

For improving the build speed of Visual Studio 2019, some attributes can be applied as follows:

1. Set Current source control plug-in to None under "Tools" -> "Options"->”Source Control ”.
2. Uncheck Synchronized Visual Studio settings across devices under "Tools" -> "Options"->”Environment ” ->”Accounts ”
   [image]
3. Uncheck Enable CodeLens under "Tools" -> "Options"->”Text Editor ” ->”All Languages ”.
   [image]
4. If you have hardware acceleration enabled, or if you use the default visual experience settings you may experience intermittent performance issues, product crashes, or rendering issues.
   You could apply the following settings under  "Tools" -> "Options"->” Environment ” ->” General ”.
   [image]
5. Delete the contents of the following directories:

Clean the content in WebSiteCache folder

(can be found in C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache).

Clean the content in Temporary ASP.NET Files folder

(can be found in C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files)

For more information, you can visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-performance-tips-and-tricks?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have achieved better performance by following your instructions and disabling some tasks in task manager setting in startup tab.

Comment: This solution worked for me with VS2022 running on an older computer.  While it wasn't a huge speed improvement, it did help considerably.  +1

Comment: was a bit faster with hardware acceleration enabled for me